# TikZ: variable in calc syntax

Tags: tikz-pgf, macros

I'd like to draw some lines where one of points should be defined like:

```
($ (A)! \X3 !(B) $)
```

where `\X3` is something from (0,1). But it's not working. Yeah, I could just place the right number, but I'd like use this construction (or quite similar) on several places of this figure and I'd like to make several figures with different `\X3`.

Any possible way how to set variable into `$ $` in TikZ?

Comment: you might not want to use numbers in your macros ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The proposed syntax works fine. I think the problem is that you have a number in the macro name.

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}


\begin{tikzpicture}
\coordinate (A) at (1,0);
\coordinate (B) at (1,2);

\newcommand*{\X}{0.3}%
\draw [ultra thick, blue, ->] (0,0) -- ($(A)!\X!(B)$);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, that was defenetly the problem. Now's working.